# SQL query with datetime value shows different result

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I execute the below query, why I am getting different result (.524 <> .523) ?

```
select convert(datetime,'2013-07-08 09:20:17.524')
```

result :  `2013-07-08 09:20:17.523`

Please advice !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL-Server's DATETIME values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds,, so this

```
select convert(datetime,'2013-07-08 09:20:17.522')
```

will also return `2013-07-08 09:20:17.523`. This is documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)

If you need to store with greater accuracy use `DATETIME2` (if it is available to you (2008+)):

```
select convert(datetime2,'2013-07-08 09:20:17.524')
```

Comment: And the `DATETIME2` datatype is available in SQL Server **2008** and newer.

Comment: humm, you are right GarethD...select convert(datetime,'2013-07-08 09:20:17.525') will get 2013-07-08 09:20:17.527 as a result

Answer (score 0):

The value gets rounded. See here under "Accuracy": http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187819.aspx?ppud=4